# How to fetch single record string value using hibernate native query?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-native-query

StudentModel studentModel;
String sql = "SELECT name from table;

Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql)

```
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(StudentModel.class));
```

studentModel= (StudentModel) query.getSingleResult();

return studentModel.getName();

Answer (score 0):

StudentModel studentModel;

String sql = "SELECT name from table;

Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql)
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(StudentModel.class));

studentModel= (StudentModel) query.getSingleResult();

return studentModel.getName()